# How to display calculated value in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Here I am getting the values to my grid. This is Connection of my database table. It is okay and working well but i want to show my Qty field data by dividing my txtOrderQuantity (textbox id name)value.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOrderQuantity" runat="server" 
            ontextchanged="txtOrderQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"> </asp:TextBox>
```

How i can show my grid view field by dividing by 2 with txtorderQuantity.

```
public DataTable GetData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  [RmId],[RmName],[MeasuringUnit],[Rate],[Qty],[BagSz]FROM [dbo].[RawMaterials]",con);
            sa.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sa.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: You can use DataBound event of gridview

Comment: i have used for data bind this code  protected void txtOrderQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                DataTable dt = new RawMaterialsProvider().GetData();
                gvTest.DataSource = dt;
                gvTest.DataBind();       
        }

Comment: No , this is just TextChange event for textbox , @Chirag mean BataBound event of `GridView` !

Comment: I didnot use data bound event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it two ways.

1) you can send the value of the text field to your GetData() method. and then prepare your select statement in the following way

```
public DataTable GetData(int OrderQuantity)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  [RmId],[RmName],[MeasuringUnit],[Rate],([Qty]/OrderQuantity )as Qty,[BagSz]FROM [dbo].[RawMaterials]",con);
        sa.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sa.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

2) you can use RowDataBound Event of GridView. it occurs when a single DataRow have bound in the gridView.

```
void YourGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    // Display the company name in italics.
   //  I assume the index of Qty column is 4
    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = decimal.Parse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text)/decimal.Parse(txtOrderQuantity.Text) ;

  }

}
```

Comment: e.Row.Cells[1].Text = decimal.Parse(e.Row.Cells[1].Text) / decimal.Parse(txtOrderQuantity.Text); cannot convert implicitly decimal to string.

Comment: e.Row.Cells[1].Text = (decimal.Parse(e.Row.Cells[1].Text) / decimal.Parse(txtOrderQuantity.Text)).ToString();

Answer (score 1):

Use RowDataBound event of gridview and perform following steps:

1. Find the textbox control and its value.
2. Find the MyQty value and divide it with textbox value(use specific type cast wherever needed.)
3. Find your control to display MyQty valud and assign calculated value.